# Modifying a MySQL database on a Ruby on Rails install

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

sorry if this questions is overly basic or has been asked before but I simply cannot figure it out.

On my Ruby on Rails site, I have a controller that accesses the fields of a table in my database and displays their "Name" field as a drop-down menu in one of my views. My problem is I need to change the options of that dropdown menu so I need a way to get into the MySQL database and change the values of those fields.

Anyone know of a way to do this? It would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking how to modify the database directly, then there are several options that you might find a little easier than using a migration. Your server may already support phpMyAdmin, a web based interface to your DB. Alternatively there are rich client apps that you can configure to manage/edit local and remote MySQL DBs. My favorite on the Mac is Sequel Pro.

Of course, you could also do this from the MySQL command line.

Comment: Yes, I have experience with phpMyAdmin and was hopeful that there was similar functionality on my work's server. However, the server is just a moshpot of different directories that they use to host several of the business' sites and lacks an easy interface for modifying the DB directly.

Comment: I access remote MySQL DBs from my Mac using Sequel Pro. There is some tricky setup in some cases, but once you are connected it is extremely convenient. Failing that, SSH and MySQL command line is an option.

Comment: Thanks Greg, your answer has helped me toward a solution.